# How to convert Arc<Mutex<Box<Struct>>> to Arc<Mutex<Box<dyn Trait>>> when a function requires Arc<Mutex<Box<dyn Trait>>> as parameter?

Tags: rust

How to convert `Arc<Mutex<Box<Struct>>>` to `Arc<Mutex<Box<dyn Trait>>>` when a function requires `Arc<Mutex<Box<dyn Trait>>>` as parameter?
In the following code snippet, the `age_plus` function requires a type of `Arc<Mutex<Box<dyn Animal>>>`, but only a type of `Arc<Mutex<Box<Dog>>>` is available.

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

pub trait Animal {
    fn age_plus(&mut self) -> u32;
}

pub struct Dog {
    age: u32,
    pub name: String,
}

impl Animal for Dog {
    fn age_plus(&mut self) -> u32 {
        self.age += 1;
        self.age
    }
}
impl Dog {
    pub fn print_name(&self) {
        println!("name: {}", self.name);
    }
}
pub fn age_plus(animal: Arc<Mutex<Box<dyn Animal>>>) {
    animal.lock().unwrap().age_plus();
}
fn main() {
    let dog = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Box::new(Dog {
        age: 10,
        name: "dog".to_string(),
    })));
    dog.lock().unwrap().print_name();
    println!("dog age: {}", dog.lock().unwrap().age_plus());
    // how to convert Arc<Mutex<Box<Dog>>> to Arc<Mutex<Box<dyn Animal>>>?
    age_plus(dog.clone());
}
```

Comment: You can't directly convert these types without stealing/copying the `Dog`. However, you could instead implement `Animal` on `Arc<Mutex<Box<T>>> where T: Animal`. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d088448a822f153af6e58d41bbb1d9af

Comment: Function requiring `Arc<Mutex<Box<dyn Trait>>>` as its input, is a *giant* code smell, and will be source of nothing than problems. Consider accepting `&mut dyn Trait` instead and locking the mutex before you call this function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If cannot modify the input parameters of age_plus,  https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8aa9649760660de687f87bd52537161e

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze "_Giant_ code smell" could be perceived as somewhat dismissive. The function might have valid reasons to accept the `Arc`, such as needing to store it somewhere. The OP has obviously simplified the use case for the sake of providing a MRE, not to mention that they might not control the definition of `age_plus()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done.

The reason is that `Box<Dog>` occupies the size of pointer bytes in memory, but `Box<dyn Animal>` occupies **double times** the size of a pointer in memory, since it also needs to store the vtable. So `Arc<Mutex<Box<Dog>>>` needs to grow to contain `Arc<Mutex<Box<dyn Animal>>>`, and that is impossible.

If you cannot change the function in any way, your only chance is cloning the type and creating a new type:

```rust
let dyn_animal = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Box::new(Dog::clone(&dog.lock().unwrap())) as _));
age_plus(dyn_animal);
```

Of course, `Dog` must be `Clone`. You might be able to avoid the clone by storing `Box<dyn Animal>` from the beginning, but it won't work if you need to call `Dog`-specific methods.

Another possible alternative, if you don't need the `Arc<Mutex>` at the beginning and don't need to call `Dog`-specific methods afterwards, is to only construct `Box<dyn Dog>`. This is easily convertible to `Box<dyn Animal>`, and it can be wrapped later with `Arc<Mutex>`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut dog = Box::new(Dog {
        age: 10,
        name: "dog".to_string(),
    });
    dog.print_name();
    println!("dog age: {}", dog.age_plus());
    let dog = Arc::new(Mutex::new(dog as Box<dyn Animal>));
    age_plus(Arc::clone(&dog));
}
```

If you can change the function, you have several options:

The best way, if possible, is to take `&mut dyn Animal` as @AleksanderKrauze said. This way you can provide all sorts of animals:

```rust
pub fn age_plus(animal: &mut dyn Animal) {
    animal.age_plus();
}
fn main() {
    let dog = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Box::new(Dog {
        age: 10,
        name: "dog".to_string(),
    })));
    dog.lock().unwrap().print_name();
    println!("dog age: {}", dog.lock().unwrap().age_plus());
    age_plus(&mut **dog.lock().unwrap());
}
```

If this is not possible, consider taking `Arc<Mutex<dyn Animal>>`. `Arc<Mutex<Dog>>` can be converted to that:

```rust
pub fn age_plus(animal: Arc<Mutex<dyn Animal>>) {
    animal.lock().unwrap().age_plus();
}
fn main() {
    let dog = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Dog {
        age: 10,
        name: "dog".to_string(),
    }));
    dog.lock().unwrap().print_name();
    println!("dog age: {}", dog.lock().unwrap().age_plus());
    age_plus(Arc::clone(&dog) as _);
}
```